# Why is changing constraints in updateConstraints faster than at other times?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have read [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2015/08/how-to-use-updateconstraints/). It states that Apple gives some advice about using the `updateConstraints` method. The part that confuses me is as follows:

> It turns out that changing a constraint inside updateConstraints is actually faster than changing a constraint at other times. The reason for that is because the engine is able to treat all the constraint changes that happen in this pass as a batch.

Why is changing a constraint inside `updateConstraints` actually faster than changing a constraint at other times?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, outside of `updateConstraints`, auto layout solves the constraint system every time you add or remove a constraint. But before calling `updateConstraints`, auto layout turns off the solver, and after `updateConstraints` returns, it turns it back on.